# Indeed how to extract the job title href link?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the code to extract the job information from Indeed, but now I want to extract the link form the job title so I can open a new page and pull out the job description information.

I can see the link on the html page with the reference to the job posting, within the href tag but not sue how to extract it?

```
import requests  
import time
from random import randint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib, requests, re, pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME["unexpectedAlertBehaviour"] = "accept"

webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
options = Options()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path='chromedriver')

driver.get("https://www.indeed.co.uk/automotive-engineer-jobs-in-uk")

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

title = [tag.text.strip() for tag in soup.select('.jobtitle')]
company = [tag.text.strip() for tag in soup.select('.company')]
location = [tag.text.strip() for tag in soup.select('.location')]

for y in range (len(title)):
    tmpstring = (title[y] + ',' + company[y] + ',' + location[y] + ",0")
    tmpstring = tmpstring.encode("utf-8")
    f = open('FileDump','a')
    f.write(tmpstring)
    f.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the child element by usig this code.

```
title_href = [tag.find("a")["href"] for tag in soup.findAll("h2",{"class":"jobtitle"})]
```

I try your code and modified a few places.because i found it can get full name from `<a>`

```
import requests  
import time
from random import randint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib, requests, re, pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME["unexpectedAlertBehaviour"] = "accept"


options = Options()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path='chromedriver')

driver.get("https://www.indeed.co.uk/automotive-engineer-jobs-in-uk")

domain = "https://www.indeed.co.uk"

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

title = [tag.find("a")["title"] for tag in soup.findAll("h2",{"class":"jobtitle"})]
title_href = [domain + tag.find("a")["href"] for tag in soup.findAll("h2",{"class":"jobtitle"})]
company = [tag.text.strip() for tag in soup.findAll("span",{"class":"company"})]
location = [tag.text.strip() for tag in soup.findAll("span",{"class":"location"})]

print(title_href)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to extract the links

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://arstechnica.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
    print link.get('href')
```

Reference 
https://pythonspot.com/extract-links-from-webpage-beautifulsoup/